# What is Linux process 'SMBD' running on my server?

Tags: centos, command-line-interface, samba

I am trying to figure out how to clean up my server, better monitor its processes and memories, and more. I came across the 'top' command and see several instances of 'smbd' and 'sshd'. I assume the latter shows active connections/processes using SSH but I am not familiar with **smbd**.

I tend to think this is 'samba' (and even if it was I have no idea what that is or what it does). Any advice if it is necessary or what the process actually does?

I have a Media Temple (MT) DV 3.5 running CentOS 5.7 for reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[smbd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smbd) is the [samba](http://www.samba.org/) server daemon that provides filesharing and printing services to Windows clients. You can safely disable it if you do not provide file/print services to windows clients.

To stop the service

```
/sbin/service smb stop
```

to disable it from starting with your system

```
/sbin/chkconfig smb off
```

Answer (score 4):

`smbd` is the Samba Daemon. You are safe to disable it as long as you don't have Windows clients for your Linux Server. You are the only one who would know so.

Comment: thanks for your help. As far as I know we do not. Is there a good 'safe' command to disable it when apache is reloaded (one in which I can re-enable if needed later).

Comment: @JM4 - samba is not related to apache at all. You would edit the system startup configuration to disable smbd (and its compliment nmbd).